# Combine individual tuple to form a list in Python

Tags: python, list, tuples, file-handling

I am learning to code and I am stuck. I trying to define a function which reads data from a file and converts it to a single list and each item in the list being a tuple having integers, floats and characters.

```
def reader(a_file):
    file = open(a_file, "r")
    listy = file.readlines()
    # print(listy)
    # print(type(listy))
    for lines in listy:
        # print(lines)
        a_list = list(lines.split())
        # print(a_list)
        short_list = []
        return_list = []
        for each in range(0, len(a_list)):
            # print(a_list[each])
            if a_list[each].isdigit() :
                each_int = int(a_list[each])
                # print(each_int)
                short_list.append(each_int)
            elif "." in a_list[each]:
                each_float = float(a_list[each])
                short_list.append(each_float)
            else:
                short_list.append(a_list[each])
            tuply = tuple(short_list)
        print(tuply)
            # return_list.append(tuply)

        # print(return_list)

    # print(return_list)
```

if i call the function using

```
print(reader("sample.cs1301"))
```

Iam able to get individual tuples
I am not able to combine individual tuples to a list.
below are the contents of the input file sample.cs1301

```
1 assignment_1 85 100 0.25
2 test_1 90 100 0.25
3 exam_1 95 100 0.5
```

I am able to get individual tuples as below

```
(1, 'assignment_1', 85, 100, 0.25)
(2, 'test_1', 90, 100, 0.25)
(3, 'exam_1', 95, 100, 0.5)
```

I have confusion in the loop. I tried searching everywhere but somehow it is not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fix original code**

```
def reader(a_file):
    file = open(a_file, "r")
    listy = file.readlines()
    file.close()         # Always close if not using with
    # print(listy)
    # print(type(listy))
    return_list = []
    for lines in listy:
        # print(lines)
        a_list = list(lines.split())
        # print(a_list)
        short_list = []
        
        for each in range(0, len(a_list)):
            # print(a_list[each])
            if a_list[each].isdigit() :
                each_int = int(a_list[each])
                # print(each_int)
                short_list.append(each_int)
            elif "." in a_list[each]:
                each_float = float(a_list[each])
                short_list.append(each_float)
            else:
                short_list.append(a_list[each])
            tuply = tuple(short_list)
        print(tuply)
        return_list.append(tuply)   # Need to append tuple to results list
        
    print(return_list)

    return return_list              # Return the resulting list

reader('sample.cs1301')
```

**Suggestions for improvement**

1. Use try/except to check on converting numbers based upon type
2. Iterator through the file line by line
3. Remove the newline at the end of line
4. Have file suffix be txt so on Window/Mac system knows the type of file i.e. 'sample.cs1301.txt'

**Improved Code**

```
def reader(filenm):
    with open(filenm, "r") as f:
        result = []
        for line in f:
            a_list = line.rstrip().split()  # rstrip to remove new line at end of line
            values = []
            for value in a_list:
                try:
                    values.append(int(value)) 
                except ValueError:                  
                    try:                         # Not int
                        values.append(float(value))
                    except ValueError:           # Not float                                              
                        values.append(value)   

            result.append(tuple(values))       # Appending values as tuple
            
    return result

print(reader('sample.cs1301.txt'))             # Use txt as file suffix
```

**Output**

```
[(1, 'assignment_1', 85, 100, 0.25),
 (2, 'test_1', 90, 100, 0.25),
 (3, 'exam_1', 95, 100, 0.5)]
```

Comment: Thank You Sir! Iam not famililiar with `with` but will take a look for sure on how the improved code functions :)

Comment: @Firearmz--using the with context manager is the standard practice.  Check out: [with](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/context-manager-in-python/)